# Why (physically) does a current divider circuit show that both resistors have an effect on individual current?

Tags: current, current-divider

I understand both the current divider formula and why it is mathematically correct. I am curious though why *physically* this is true. My book provided me the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu8Hmr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The explanation in the book left a lot to be desired. The physical explanation was basically:

1. The total current from the source *I* is split into two currents *I1* and *I2* at the junction of the parallel resistors. *I1* passes through *R1* and *I2* passes through *R2* respectively.
2. They are recombined at the other side so that the current and voltage across them are made whole again.

From the formula, the current *x* across a given resistor *x* is given by:

`Ix = It * (Rt)/(Rx + Rt)`

and so from the formula it's clear the *total* resistance (and therefore the other resistors including the branch's resistors) has an effect on a given individual branch of current.

Why physically is this effect true? It seems counter-intuitive in the sense that you might expect *only* the branch's resistor, rather than both resistors, to effect the current.

Comment: Rt is not total resistance here.  Perhaps you should choose a different subscript.

Comment: That formula holds if your circuit is being driven by a *current source*. The one you've drawn has a *voltage source* - and your intuition in this case is correct.

Comment: Consider the current per resistor is defined by the voltage that is across each resistor. Then the current through each resistor is independent of the other.

Comment: I had taken the formula from wikipedia out of sheer laziness @ScottSeidman (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider). It seems Rt is indeed total resistance.

Comment: No - Rt is not the "total" resistance. In the given formula, the current It must be replaced by the total current I=V1/(R1+R2) - that`s all.

Comment: No, Rt is on that website defined as the total resistance right of Rx. So Rt = R2 in your question.

Comment: I did not check any website.....I have calculated the circuit with just two resistors.

Comment: Remark was addressed to @CL40

Comment: The circuit shown is *not* a current divider.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Can you explain how it is not? It is exactly the circuit in my book verbatim, it agrees with the circuit in this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VojwBoSHc8U) as well. If it is not, there's an entire wall of EE books that need to be rewritten.

Comment: It doesn't agree with the circuit in the video, which does *not* show a *voltage source*.  Note that the wikipedia entry shows a *current source*, and I'd almost guarantee your book shows either nothing (like the video), or a current source.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Pg 24. "Complete Electronics Self-Teaching Guide" shows a symbol for a battery (https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/schematic-symbols-battery.png) which I thought was a voltage source (and would be _very_ surprised if it wasn't), so I substituted an ideal voltage source into the schematic above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in assuming that the current through R1 does not depend on the resistor R2 (resp. the current through R2).

However, because both independent currents are driven by a commom voltage source - and because I1+I2=I - you can replace the Voltage V1 in the expression I1=V1/R1 by the other current I2 and I. The same applies vice versa to I2.

By doing this, you arrive at the given expression for Ix (If x=1, we have t=2 and if x=2, we have t=1).

**In detail**: I1=I[R2/(R1+R2)] and I2=I[R1/(R1+R2)]

Summary: Answering your question (headline), it seems that the resistor R2 would have an influence on the current I1 - however, this is not true. We only have expressed the driving voltage V1 by the total current which also depends on R2 (and vice versa).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90629/discussion-on-answer-by-lvw-why-physically-does-a-current-divider-circuit-show).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answers.

Comment: Univ. of Berkeley: "Thus, current entering a set of parallel resistors splits such that more current passes through the less resistive path". You disagree - well, WHAT DO YOU DISAGREE WITH? With the applicability of the mentioned rule for each resistive parallel combination? Or just with the name? I think, the name "current division" for the circuit under discussion is in full accordance with all relevant textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula is wrong:

If \$I_t\$ is defined as \$I_x+I_y\$ and \$R_t\$ is defined as  \$\frac{R_x R_y}{(R_x +R_y)} \$ then

$$ V = I_t * R_t $$
$$ I_x = V/R_x $$

$$ I_x = I_t * R_t/R_x $$
**not**
$$ I_t * (R_t)/(R_x + R_t)$$

If \$I_t\$ is defined as \$I_x+I_y\$ and \$R_t\$ is defined as  \$ (R_x +R_y) \$ then the formula given by OP becomes

$$I_x = I_t * (R_t)/(R_x + R_t)$$
$$I_x = I_t * (R_x +R_y)/(R_x + R_x +R_y)$$
which makes no sense either.

Were V2 a current source, then it still makes no sense.
The current source equals \$I_t\$ and V in above equations is still the voltage across both resistors.

So, either it is 
$$I x =I_t ∗R_t /R_x$$ or like @ScottSeidman already remarked, Rt is not the total resistance.

Comment: x and t are just indices.....and in the original formula, It is wrong and must be replaced by the total current I.

Comment: Like I already did. The first approach equals your answer.